# Separate Editor badge and other usages of word "Editor" in translations

Tags: feature-request, review, badges, localization

On Stack Overflow in Russian we have ["Младший редактор"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor) badge. This is a creative translation of original badge named "Editor". The translation "Младший редактор" (junior editor) is chosen since another badge (["Strunk & White"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) in original) has been translated as "Редактор" ("Editor").

> [image: All badges]

All these translations were fine before we found "Editor" as a title in review queue table, e.g. see [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/669955):

> [image: Junior editor in review]

In the term of reviewers translation "Младший редактор" is not suitable. And I'm asking to add contexts for the word "Editor" (at least one for badges, another for anything else) in translation DB to allow us choose different translations in different cases. Thanks in advance.